# Converting post curl to node request

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl

I would like to convert this curl call:

```
curl -d "api_token=PUT_YOUR_API_KEY_HERE&api_action=subscription_datafeed" https://example.foxycart.com/api
```

To node using the request lib - https://github.com/mikeal/request but I am having issues getting the body sent. My curl call works fine but when I convert it I keep getting the same error about api_token and api_action missing.  Here's what I tried:

```
var options = {
  url: 'https://example.foxycart.com/api',
  body: JSON.stringify({
    api_token:'PUT_YOUR_API_KEY_HERE',
    api_action:'subscription_datafeed'
  }),
  method: 'POST'
  };

request(options, function (error, response, body) { });
```

Also:

```
var options = {
  url: 'https://example.foxycart.com/api',
  json: {
    api_token:'PUT_YOUR_API_KEY_HERE',
    api_action:'subscription_datafeed'
  },
  method: 'POST'
  };

request(options, function (error, response, body) { });
```

Also this:

```
var options = {
  url: 'https://example.foxycart.com/api',
  body: '?api_token=PUT_YOUR_API_KEY_HERE&api_action=subscription_datafeed',
  method: 'POST'
  };

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
```

Also this:

```
var options = {
  url: 'https://example.foxycart.com/api',
  body: 'api_token=PUT_YOUR_API_KEY_HERE&api_action=subscription_datafeed',
  method: 'POST'
  };

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
```

And this:

```
request.post('https://example.foxycart.com/api?api_token=PUT_YOUR_API_KEY_HERE&api_action=subscription_datafeed', function (error, response, body) { });
```

Here's a PHP one that supposedly works for a similar call on same API - seems like I have the code correct but...

```
$foxy_domain = "myfoxydomain.foxycart.com";
$foxyData = array();
$foxyData["api_token"] = "XXXXX your api / datafeed key here XXXXXX";
$foxyData["api_action"] = "customer_save";
$foxyData["customer_id"] = "12345";
// OR use the email:
//$foxyData["customer_email"] = "customer@example.com";
$foxyData["customer_password"] = "my new password";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://" . $foxy_domain . "/api");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $foxyData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
var options = {
  url: 'https://example.foxycart.com/api',
  form: {
    api_token:'PUT_YOUR_API_KEY_HERE',
    api_action:'subscription_datafeed'
  },
  method: 'POST'
};

request(options, function (error, response, body) { });
```